# how are we able to use the less than sign( '<'or even greater than( '>') ) in #include directive if c doesn't support operator overloading?

Tags: c, operator-overloading, c-preprocessor

We all know that c doesn't support operator overloading.Can anyone tell me if that is so, then how are we able to use the less than sign in the **#include** directive and in **comparison** also? Or the functionality provided is called  something else and defined in language?

Comment: Operators handled by a parser/compiler. `#include` is a preprocessor directive which works prior parser, through it has different syntax

Comment: preprocessor directive is different from logical operation symbol, preprocessor directives are used in preprocessor stage that has different syntax, both cannot be compared

Comment: There's no operator overloading here. Neither the compiler or the user redefines that operator. It's a syntax thing, like `*` operator meaning depends on context even though no one overloads it

Comment: Even in operator overloading you kind of define that you want the operator to do something different when the context is "this".So how is it different?

Comment: can the downvoter please mention what  have you downvoted for?what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many symbols in C have different meaning depending on context.

Example:

`*`  can mean either multiplication or pointer dereference.

Such dual meanings  makes it a bit tricky to write a C parser and even trickier to provide helpful error messages when the code doesn't compile.

Note that this dual meaning is **not** operator overloading. They are two separate operators.

When it comes to `#include` directives the answer is that they are processed by the pre-processor. After the pre-processor step the `<` and `>` are gone - the line has been replaced by the entire contents of the include file.

Comment: okay but doesn't the pre-processor knows that it is a less than symbol when processing the #include directiive?

Comment: When processing an `#include` directive the pre-processor expects one of two things; either `<filename>` or `"filename"`. If it finds one of those it is happy, otherwise it will generate an error message. In this context, it knows that `<` and `>` doesn't mean  "less than" and "greater than".

Comment: Got it .So it's defined somewhere that the preprocessor will only work when it encounters **<filename>** or **"filename"**  ? Like the syntax?

Comment: it's not seeing a "less than" sign, it's looking for an angle bracket

Comment: @PushpinderSinghGrewal The preprocessor looks for preprocessor directives (there are others, but they all begin with `#`). When it finds one, it does different things depending on which preprocessor directive it finds.

Comment: @klas lindback Are you sure that they both are different operators?

Comment: @PushpinderSinghGrewal I am positive. One is binary (multiplication) and the other unary (dereferencing a pointer).

Comment: Yes they are different operators( 1 is for multiply and other is for indirection) .I googled all operators in c and found the list.However ,i found no evidence about the **<** in #include

Comment: @PushpinderSinghGrewal  See for example https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC6 for the syntax of the `#include` pre-processor directive.

Comment: Thank you @klas Lindback

Answer (score 3):

Though normally we simply invoke something like `gcc file.c` to compile our source file, and though we say we 'compile', there's a pretty bunch of various things happening under the hood.

One of the first thing that happens to a source file is preprocessing. The source, as you wrote it down, gets fed into a preprocessor. The preprocessor cares only about `#`-started lines, including, well... `#include <header.h>`

Once the preprocessor has finished it's job all those `<header.h>` are substituted by the `header.h`'s actual content, so that your source file is only now ready to actually be compiled by a compiler. Try `gcc -E file.c` to see what happens.

Now C compiler steps in. Any `<` or `>` it sees are comparison operators only.

Once again: `#include <header.h>` directive is for preprocessor, all the rest is for compiler. The latter work after the former.

Answer (score 1):

> The most common example of this is the C preprocessor, which takes lines beginning with '#' as directives. **Because it knows nothing about the underlying language**... ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor#Lexical_preprocessors))

The preprocessor does not know that "<" is "less than". It, much like Jon Snow, knows nothing, so this is not operator-overloading, it is simply following other lexical rules

[this](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html) shows a lexical specification for ANSI-C grammar. Note that there are rules like

```
"="         { count(); return('='); }
```

and like

```
"=="            { count(); return(EQ_OP); }
```

The lexer knows to return the best fit for what it sees. It knows that when seeing `x==y` that does not mean `x=` and `=` and `y` which have no meaning... same for "<" and "#include<" but that is a part of a different grammar

Comment: Actually it knows about less operator and can handle it in `#if` directive. Through, it is different directive than `#include`.

Comment: @myaut I disagree. the rules it follows state the "<" means less, but "#include<" means "blah-blah-blah". the C language doesn't have these same rules

Comment: so what it is like? does the preprocessor doesn't know about the less than sign when it's handling #include and suddenly knows about it when it comes to #if ?  confused !

Comment: it knows that seeing "<" alone means "less than" but seeing it with "#include" means another thing. much like "int x = 2-2" and "int x = 2--". the first "-" is "minus" and the second is a part of "--"

Comment: Thank you for the help @noob